# Getting the length of a list as string

Tags: python, list, logging

Ok simple question, please don't kill me.

To log the length of a list I do:

```
logger.info("the length of my list is: " + str(len(mylist)));
```

Is there a better way to do it in python?

Comment: Define "better". What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: I'd guess he means 'more pythonic'

Comment: Better - easier to read and better practise. Yes more pythonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do something like:

```
logger.info('the length of my list is %d' % len(mylist))
```

Comment: Thanks but why is that better? you have got rid of the str but then you have introduced a varibale %d so synatically is it any cleaner?

Comment: I like this format since it's easier to add other info to the string and have it remain readable. Also I spend most of my time in C.

Comment: I guess you use %d to indicate number as opposed to %d?  Yeah.

Answer (score 8):

I'd do something like this:

```
logger.info('the length of my list is: {0}'.format(len(mylist)))
```

Edit: For more information about why `format` is supposed to be better than `%`, please have a look at [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/):

> The '%' operator is primarily limited by the fact that it is a
>   binary operator, and therefore can take at most two arguments.
>   One of those arguments is already dedicated to the format string,
>   leaving all other variables to be squeezed into the remaining
>   argument.  The current practice is to use either a dictionary or a
>   tuple as the second argument, but as many people have commented
>   [3], this lacks flexibility.  The "all or nothing" approach
>   (meaning that one must choose between only positional arguments,
>   or only named arguments) is felt to be overly constraining.

Also note that you can even add your own custom formatting to your objects. Hence, you aren't constraint to a set of already defined conversion characters, but you can define your own mini language for formatting your objects according to your needs. This is something really powerful not available through `%`.

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format):

> **format(value[, format_spec])**
>
> Convert a value to a “formatted” representation, as controlled by format_spec. The interpretation of format_spec will depend on the type of the value argument, however there is a standard formatting syntax that is used by most built-in types: Format Specification Mini-Language.

Comment: Thanks but why is that better?

Comment: It may be micro-optimisation,  but https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136968/1587520 should be the correct answer, as it does string substitution only when needed (i.e. the logger is active at the used level).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
logger.info('the length of my list is: %s', len(mylist))
```

Which will perform the substitution only if the logger is enabled for the `INFO` level. Therefore, this makes it slightly faster than doing the substitution in the message before  logging it when the logger isn't enabled.

You can also pass more arguments or a `dict` instead:

```
>>> logging.info('%s %s %s', 1,2,3)
INFO:root:1 2 3
>>> logging.info('%(foo)s %(bar)s', {'foo': 'FOO', 'bar': 'BAR'})
INFO:root:FOO BAR
```

[`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) uses the string formatting operator. For other purposes, `format()` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to add a specific kind of information over and over, you can provide a custom format and use the `extra` keyword.

For example:

```
FORMAT = "'%(message)s' is long: %(length)d"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()
d = {'length': 30}
logger.info('my message', extra=d)
```

Would give you something like:

```
'my message' is long: 30
```